# Download array of images and play on table cell in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I download set of images from server and display those images inside table cell. Could you help with completion block or delegate. Example will be really appreciated.

```html
[tableCell.playerView addSubview:imagePlayerView];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [imagePlayerView downloadImages];
             });
```

Comment: Are you using `Alamofire`?

Comment: I think yes but I am really new to this.. Could you help here?

Comment: Try with my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good way to add subview `imagePlayerView` in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, because on reload it will again create and load, so use custom cell for arranging view.

> ```
> // Not a good way to do that
> [tableCell.playerView addSubview:imagePlayerView];
> ```

Create a custom cell for your table view with `UIImageView` on cell. Refer the link https://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

**In your view controller class:**

Follow the below steps:

1. Import `AFNetworking+UIImageView` in your view controller file
2. Update `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

> ```
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>     static cellIdentifier = "cellidentifier";
>     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
>
>     NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:"Your Url"];
>     [cell.imageProfPic setImageWithURL:url]; // Supposing "imageProfPic" is the UIImageView in your cell's custom class
>
>     return cell
> }
> ```

Comment: This is correct answer for showing images in table cell. My question wasn't right.. I have to play these set of images inside one cell view like animation once download completed.